# Why is the velocity squared in the lift equation?

Tags: aerodynamics

Why is the velocity $v$ squared in the lift equation?
$$L=C_L\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\rho\cdot v^2\cdot S$$

Comment: Can you share the formula you are asking about?

Comment: At a very high level of abstraction, it's because you're hitting more air per unit of time (proportional to v) and you're hitting each bit of air with more momentum (also proportional to v). (At least, that's why drag is proportional to v^2; I assume it holds for lift.)

Answer (score 10):

Newton's second law is:

$$F = ma$$

The $m$ass in the lift equation is of the fluid's, mass times velocity is the fluid momentum. So the equation can be written as:

$$F = {\Delta}(mv)/{\Delta}t$$

Rearrange that equation and it becomes:

$$F = \text{constant}
\cdot
(m/t)v$$

Mass over time is the [mass flow rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_flow_rate):

$$m/t = {\rho}vA$$

So we end up with:

$$F = \text{constant}
\cdot
{\rho}vAv$$

Which is:

$$F = \text{constant}
\cdot
{\rho}v^2A$$

Add $A$ to the constant:

$$F = \text{constant}
\cdot
{\rho}v^2$$

---

Reference: [NASA](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/momntm.html)

Comment: It's not F=mv/t, but F=m$\Delta$v/t

Comment: The ½ comes from an integration step, but never mind.

Comment: -1, Derivation is wrong, or, at best, misleading.  The `A` in Mass flow rate is not the same as the `S` in the Lift equation. The `A` is the cross-sectional area through which the mass is flowing, (normal to the flow), not the surface area of the airfoil.

Comment: @CharlesBretana - fixed the $A$ part, thanks, rest is correct backed up by the link.

Comment: removed my downvote, thanks for correcting that.. Also suggest you think hard about starting out with $F=ma$. I believe there's a flaw there.  The idea is substantively correct, but I think (not positive), that the NASA derivation is about flow through an engine, or a defined cross-sectional area, and not for lift on an airfoil. But they both proportional to $V^2$ for the same reason - change in momentum, which is what you're getting at.

Comment: There are two different $v$s here: the first $v$ in $F=\Delta(mv)/\Delta t$ is $v_y$, vertical component of velocity, while the second $v$ in $m/t = \rho v A$ is $v_x$, the horizontal component of velocity. Fortunately the derivation can be salvaged by observing that $\Delta v_y = \sin\alpha' v_x$ (where $\alpha'$ is the angle, by which the air is deflected, with explanation why $C_L\propto\alpha$ as a bonus).

Comment: You also dropped the $\Delta$s (or I would prefer $d$s) too early—they should be there up to the mass flow rate equation.

Comment: … of course you got it straight from that NASA page, which just shows that even NASA folks sometimes oversimplify things when trying to explain them.

Answer (score 4):

Kinetic Energy is why the V<sup>2</sup> is  there.  The formula for kinetic energy is:

$$E_{kin} = \frac{1}{2}\cdot m\cdot v^2$$

and the greek letter rho is the density of the air which is mass per unit volume.  So you can see the formula for kinetic energy in the lift equation.  Cool huh?  So what the lift equation is telling you is that the kinetic energy of the wing moving through the air is responsible for lift and we all know that you need velocity to lift a plane off the ground.  This also tells you that velocity is the biggest contributing factor to the lift component so airspeed gives you lift more than anything else.